# Selecting/Deselecting CheckBoxes from Unique columns with Jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview, checkbox

I have a grid view with multiple check box columns and I was wondering if anyone could show me how to select all check boxes in a unique column.  I don't want to select a check box in the header and have it select all the check boxes in the grid view.  I'm new to jQuery, literally at the beginners stage and was hoping to be able to do it in jquery.

Thanks in Advance,
Terry

Answer (score 0):

all checkbox has to be the class = "myClass"

```
$(".myClass").attr("checked", true);
```

Extended example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-ui-1.7.custom/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            alert('before')
            $(".myClass").attr("checked", true);
            alert('after')
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb5" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb6" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb7" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb8" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb9" class="myClass" value="false">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb0" class="myClass" value="false">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Andre, I tried your solution as well and no luck.  I get the same error I posted to Andra below....

Comment: I only have 600 characters to display my html and it goes way over.
basically, when the browser reads this line:
$(".Bill1").attr("checked", true);
The browser gives the following error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object

all of the checkboxes are in a gridview and all have a class="Bill1" assigned to them.  
If I use document.getelementbyid I see that the checkboxes exist, but with the jquery using $(document).ready(function()
      {
          $(".Bill1").attr("checked", false);
});
it crashes..why can't jquery see the checkbox?

Terry

Comment: How the 600 characters are created? could put the code of checkboxs, to see the html.

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming you want to specify the column index.
var selectedColumnIndex = 2; 

$('td:nth-child(' + selectedColumnIndex + ')').each( function(){
   $(":checkbox", $(this)).attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Hi Andra, I tried your solution, but I get the following error in javascript:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object 

I believe I have to reference the gridview before referencing the columns don't I?

Comment: Hi TGS, show me some your GridView markup. also, please tag asp.net on your question.